# Replace string C# not working

Tags: c#, string

i have two string variables named X and Y respectively.  What i want is to replace the X string from the Y variable. I'm using the command string.replace put nothing comes through. 
the code i'm using is shown below, 
thanks 
Stavros Afxentis

```
        string Y= string.Empty;
        string X= string.Empty;

            Y= get_y_value(...);            // my method to get string y
            X= get_x_vale(...);            // my method to get string X
            Y= Y.Replace(X, "");
        // i also used Y= Y.Replace(X.ToString(), "");
        // but the result is the same
```

Comment: Then X was not found in Y, not even once. It works exactly as it is documented to work.

Comment: If you post your actual code / more code, it might help. With the code you've shown, Y is always `string.Empty` no matter what X is, so there is no way you're going to replace anything.

Comment: actually i forgot to write the part of the code that i get the vaue of string Y... So string Y is not empty

Answer (score 2):

Replace is used to change a "word" inside another string. Like so:

```
string badString = "Can I has the code";
string goodString = badString.Replace("has", "have");
```

Your biggest problem is that both strings are Empty.

Answer (score 0):

The code should work flawlessly it will remove the string X because you are replacing it with 0 length string, there might be 2 reasons why this isn't working,
1) X not found in Y
2) You didn't print or show the updated Y

Answer (score -1):

finally i used the code below, where i converted the string to char array and i removed the unwanted text.. pseudocode below:

```
          int i=0;
           while ((i<Y.Length) && (counter<1))
            {
                //ignore part of the string
               // and save the position of the char array i want
             }

        while (poss<Y.Length)
       { 
         new_ch[poss] = ch[poss]           //save the array to new char array
       }
  string y_new = new string(new_ch);
```